# restrict xpath within nested element

Tags: xpath

I want to find all index terms by section, but sections are nested. Here is a simple example.

```
<chapter>
  <section><title>First Top Section</title>
    <indexterm text="dog"/>
    <para>
      <indexterm text="tree"/>
    </para>
    <section><title>SubSection</title>
      <indexterm text="cat"/>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section><title>Second Top Section</title>
    <indexterm text="elephant" />
  </section>
</chapter>
```

Is there any xpath expression to get a result like this:

```
First Top Section = ["dog", "tree"]
Subsection = ["cat"]
Second Top Section = ["elephant"]
```

Of course I get all the descendant indexterms under a section with an expression like this:

```
/chapter/section//indexterm
```

But indexterms can be inside other elements in a section--they're not necessarily children.

Is it possible to get indexterms specific to their parent section using xpath?

Comment: Are you ok with XPATH 2.0?

Comment: No, my tools do not allow for 2.0 yet.

Comment: Which "tools" are you using?  What programming language, XPath library, etc.?

Comment: python with lxml (which uses libxml2/libxslt). Also xsltproc on unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a predicate at the `section` level:

```
/chapter/section[title = 'First Top Section']//indexterm
```

but this will include all indexterm elements under the given section, including those in subsections.  To exclude them you could do something like

```
/chapter/section[title = 'First Top Section']//indexterm[count(ancestor::section) = 1]
```

to pick out those indexterm elements that have exactly one `section` ancestor (i.e. the "First Top Section" you started with).

More generally, if you have a reference to a specific `section` element then you can get all the indexterm elements inside it but not inside a subsection by first evaluating

```
count(ancestor-or-self::section)
```

as a number, and with the current `section` element as the context node, and then build up another expression

```
.//indexterm[count(ancestor::section) = thenumberyoujustcounted]
```

and evaluate that as a node set, again with the original `section` element as the context node.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use XPath 2.0, you could do:

**XML Input**

```
<chapter>
    <section><title>First Top Section</title>
        <indexterm text="dog"/>
        <para>
            <indexterm text="tree"/>
        </para>
        <section><title>SubSection</title>
            <indexterm text="cat"/>
        </section>
    </section>
    <section><title>Second Top Section</title>
        <indexterm text="elephant" />
    </section>
</chapter>
```

**XPath 2.0**

```
for $section in //section 
return concat($section/title,' - ["',
       string-join($section//indexterm[ancestor::section[1] is $section]/@text,
       '", "'),'"]&#xA;')
```

**Output**

```
First Top Section - ["dog", "tree"]
SubSection - ["cat"]
Second Top Section - ["elephant"]
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion and malformed example. I did mean the sections are nested, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Somehow I missed "sections can be nested" in the very first sentence :-/ My apologies.

Comment: `generate-id` is XSLT specific, but you can use `ancestor::section[1] is $section` to the same effect, which is pure XPath (2.0).

Comment: @IanRoberts - Good catch. That's what I get for using XSLT to test. I've updated my answer.